# Refactoring this java sql code snippet

Tags: java, sql, refactoring

I want to combine these 2 sql queries into 1, is that possible? I am not a SQL expert unfortunately.

My current code snippet with the 2 queries is as follows:

```
if(myFlag.equals("") || isFlagPirate.equals("N")){

    //get list of available ship id, ship name as options for the ship dropdown list
    sqlShipListString =
            "select distinct ship.ship_id, ship.name from admiralty_branch  " +
                    "left join ship on ship.ship_id=admiralty_branch.ship_id " +
                    "where admiralty_branch_id= " + admiraltyid +
                    " order by ship.name";

}else{

    if(isFlagPirate.equals("Y")){           

        //get list of available ship id, ship name as options for the ship dropdown list
        sqlShipListString =
                "select distinct ship.ship_id, ship.name from ship  " +
                        "left join ship_type on ship.ship_id=ship_type.ship_id " +
                        "left join fleet on ship_type.fleet_id=fleet.fleet_id " +
                        "where fleet_id= " + fleetId +
                        " order by ship.name";
    }
}
```

As requested, table structures:

```
**ship**
ship_id
name

**admiralty_branch**
admiralty_branch_id
ship_id

**ship_type**
ship_id
fleet_id

**fleet**
fleet_id
```

Comment: Why do you want to combine them into one query? You are only going to run one or the other, based on your if/then.

Comment: yes, the table structures would be good to look at first too...

Comment: sure, i will put up the table structures asap! appreciate the comments!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ugly solution. The 2 left joins for pirates vs 1 for non pirates makes for a difference in the pattern. I wouldn't refactor for just these 2 queries. If you have more you could consider creating an sqlbuilder of some sort.

```
public String getSql(String isFlagPirate)
{
    if(myFlag .equals("") || isFlagPirate.equals("N")){

        //get list of available ship id, ship name as options for the ship dropdown list
        return
                buildSql("admiralty_branch  ", "ship on ship.ship_id=admiralty_branch.ship_id ", 
                        "admiralty_branch_id", admiraltyid);

    }else{

        if(isFlagPirate.equals("Y")){           

            //get list of available ship id, ship name as options for the ship dropdown list
            return buildSql("ship  ", "ship_type on ship.ship_id=ship_type.ship_id left join fleet on ship_type.fleet_id=fleet.fleet_id ",
                    "fleet_id", fleetId);
        }
        return "";
    }
}

protected String buildSql(String table, String leftjoin, String whereFieldName, String whereFieldValue)
{
    return "select distinct ship.ship_id, ship.name from "+table +
            "left join "+leftjoin +
            "where "+whereFieldName+"= " + whereFieldValue +
            " order by ship.name";
}
```